Full username in process snapshot format
I'm trying to get processes snapshot of PM2 usage
bitrix    1948  4.0  0.9 1586136 748292 ?      Ssl  Apr09 426:12 PM2 v5.2.2: God Daemon (/home/bitrix/.pm2)

by
ps waxfu | grep "[P]M"

but get also lines start with
usern+

I've tried way with user:[length] but get error: unsupported option (BSD syntax).
I want to get every PM2 process, then get its full-size username to use that username with runuser -l $user -c "pm2 list"
How to solve the issue?
username1    1948  4.0  0.5 1282136 401776 ?      Ssl  Apr09 439:05 PM2 v5.2.2: God Daemon (/home/username1/.pm2)
userna+  1954  0.0  0.0 901844 18312 ?        Ssl  Apr09   0:04 PM2 v5.2.0: God Daemon (/home/username2/.pm2)
use+ 20428  0.0  0.0 706176 27384 ?        Ssl  Apr15   0:01 PM2 v5.2.2: God Daemon (/home/username3/.pm
root     12857  0.0  0.0 630240 15808 ?        Ssl  07:33   0:00 PM2 v5.2.2: God Daemon (/root/.pm2)


Why are you grepping for [P]M instead of just PM? Anyways what do you mean by "get also lines start with"? You mean "The line must BOTH start with usern+ AND contain PM"? What is exactly usern+, can you provide an example of a line with usern+ in it? Cause it seems as though you're not looking to match against a literal usern+ string, correct?

Also, what information about the process are you trying to gather here? Cause this might be a job for pgrep.

@kos
I want to get every PM2 process, then get its full-size username to use that username with
runuser -l $user -c "pm2 list"

The only way I can get full names is grep them by part from /etc/passwd.
But it looks ozzy.

Indeed. Please see if the command I posted is what you actually want

Hold up though what do you mean by "full name"?

@kos greping for [P]M is standard procedure when greping ps output for PM so that the grep command's regexp ([P]M = P followed immediately by M) doesn't match the appearance of the grep command in the ps output ... grep '[P]M]' if it happens to appear in it as that does not contain a P followed immediately by M. Hope that makes sense. If not, see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/74185/how-can-i-prevent-grep-from-showing-up-in-ps-results.

@EdMorton Yes, but the problem is they're mentioning P[M]right after saying "I'm trying to get processes snapshot of PM2 usage", and PM2 actually appears in all their sample ouitputs, so I finally read it as they were actually trying to match PM2 (shortened to PM) but then got confused and actually tried matching P[M]. The question indeed is unclear.

Unfortunately pgrep won't list IDs of processes not connected to a TTY. That's why the method I previously posted didn't work for you (I'll leave it below for those who don't have such a requirement).
I couldn't find something better than this mess to achieve what you're after, hopefully someone else will chime in and post a way to do this in a cleaner way:
ps waxfo user:100=,command= | awk '/PM2/ {print $1}'

Also, not requested, but possibly required, to filter out possible duplicate users (in case some of them are running multiple instances of PM2):
ps waxfo user:100=,command= | awk '/PM2/ {print $1}' | sort -u

I removed the u option and I replaced it with the o user:100=,command= option in order to avoid truncation of usernames up to 100 characters long and in order to reduce the number of columns in the output, to prevent collisions as much as possible, and I replaced the pattern with PM2 (swapping grep for awk, to be able to also filter out fields other than the first one at the same time) for the same reason. sort -u will filter out possible duplicate users.

As per the comments, if I understood correctly, unless the target processes are not connected to a TTY:
ps -o user= -p $(pgrep PM2)

Will find every process including PM2 in the process name and print, for each match, the username of the owner.

$(pgrep PM2): returns a list of PIDs including PM2 in the process name
-o user=: sets the format of the output to the single "user" column, discarding the header
-p: filters processes based on a PID list

For example, my username is "user" and I have 5 zsh processes running.
If I run ps -o user= -p $(pgrep zsh):
user@[REDACTED] ~ % ps -o user= -p $(pgrep zsh)
user
user
user
user
user


I have 4 users work with PM2 at the server, but pgrep return only process of one of the users.

@palmasd1 Can you add the output of ps waxfu | grep "[P]M" to your question?

Pasted a part of output

@palmasd1 See my updated answer for an explanation and an additional method, let me know if worked out ok

If I get the OP correctly "looking at usern+ and I've tried way with user:[length]" ... I think they want to increase the field for the username to display the full usernames ... Something like ps waxfo user:30,command= ... But they use the u option in addition and get the error.

@kos I did it my own way, cause I'm tired(

@Raffa Good call, I actually asked OP what they meant by full name (and they never replied), I now also read it like that, I think this is incidentally fixed by using o user=,... though (at least on my system truncation on the output is no more, but I'm not sure if that turned it off altoghether or just mitigated it)

@palmasd1 If the way you did that is what you posted in your deleted answer, I really suggest you use  this method instead, that is kind of a mess :|

If you're still getting truncated fields, use the method @Raffa outlined to fix that in my answer (which I now understand is what you were trying to do all along). But still, all you need to do is filtering once, not using that huge pipeline :|

@Raffa Ok I tested it, when using o I'm unable to get fields truncated without explicitly setting e.g. column:1 (column won't ever get truncated), so it could be that : is there to limit the output. I'm not sure, I changed the answer to truncate to 100 characters, which should be always fine. But I was wondering if you knew how the colon is supposed to work exactly, as now I'm curious.

The colon : followed by a number is indeed used to set (mainly expand) the column's width .,. If a header string is provided after = like user=MyLongUsernameField, the column width will expand to the width of the provided string … If no header is provided after = then no header is printed and long usernames might get shortened … However, probably not all ps implementations support : but GNU does.

I have now tried it and usernames excess of 7 characters get shortened even with o … I don’t know why they don’t get shortened on your system but expanding the user field with e.g. user:30 was needed in my test to display full usernames more than 7 characters long.

@Raffa Cheers! the machine I initially tried this on was a server installation with a much cleaner process tree, so perhaps I just wasn't getting commands long enough to trigger truncation. Good to know :)

@kos I deleted my answer due I forgot to include there runuser part. I'm trying to do it rn.

@palmasd1 The way you did it is very unsafe. My way isn't perfect either, but your answer 1. Will break if the username contains regex special characters (or shell special characters) 2. grep + awk may very well be just awk, I too had that problem in my answer, it's just not needed 3. If two or more similar usernames are truncated very short, you'll end up missing some 4. If the truncated part of the username matches another username somewhere in the middle of the string, that username will be returned too

@palmasd15. /etc/passwd doesn't list all users, so you might miss some users, but if that's not a concern then 6. Instead of parsing /etc/passwd, you might as well call getent passwd username | cut -d':' -f1 7. You don't need sort in the body of the do loop, unless you expect the previous part to be broken (which it is) and return more than one line.

@palmasd1 The only good thing it does is sorting the output before calling uniq, which I forgot to do in my answer (btw sort + uniq = sort -u)

Your question isn't clear but if this block of text from your question:
$ cat file
username1    1948  4.0  0.5 1282136 401776 ?      Ssl  Apr09 439:05 PM2 v5.2.2: God Daemon (/home/username1/.pm2)
userna+  1954  0.0  0.0 901844 18312 ?        Ssl  Apr09   0:04 PM2 v5.2.0: God Daemon (/home/username2/.pm2)
use+ 20428  0.0  0.0 706176 27384 ?        Ssl  Apr15   0:01 PM2 v5.2.2: God Daemon (/home/username3/.pm
root     12857  0.0  0.0 630240 15808 ?        Ssl  07:33   0:00 PM2 v5.2.2: God Daemon (/root/.pm2)

is intended to be sample input (output of your ps command) and you want to print the first field from each line that starts with usern and contains PM2 then that'd be (using cat file in place of your ps command just for demonstrating the awk` command here):
$ cat file | awk '/^usern/ && /[P]M2/ { print $1 }'
username1
userna+

If you only want unique user names printed then change the awk script to:
awk '/^usern/ && /[P]M2/ && !seen[$1]++ { print $1 }'

If that's not what you're trying to do then please edit your question to clarify your requirements and provide concise, testable sample input and the expected output given that input that demonstrates those requirements and we can copy/paste to test with.
